# What's the process for implementing dynamic selection of configuration files in a codebase that supports multiple devices?

Tags: c, architecture, embedded, runtime, freertos

I am working with two closely related devices that share most similarities but also have distinct differences. Specifically, Device 1 represents an older iteration of Device 2. Each device has its own separate codebase (written in C). My goal is to merge these codebases into a unified one that can dynamically adapt and properly expose relevant default and configuration files based on the connected device.

The key requirement here is that these values need to be determined during runtime. I'm currently unsure about the approach to enable the selection of a **config.h** file at runtime.

Project Structure:

```
parent directory
│
├── device1_config
│   └── config.h
│
├── device2_config
│   └── config.h
│
└── Source files
```

The project is developed within SoftConsole. The device is detected by reading from a register. At the moment, I have set up two distinct build configurations, each with its own path pointing to the corresponding **config.h** file. But this is a violation of the runtime configuration requirement.

I'm currently grappling with the challenge of implementing adaptable runtime code that accommodates different hardware configurations. How can I achieve this effectively?

So far, I've explored a few approaches to achieve the selection of the **config.h** file and the adaptable codebase:

1. I experimented with using preprocessor directives within the source code to conditionally incorporate the relevant **config.h** file based on the specific device type or configuration. However, this approach only addressed the determination at compile time, not during runtime.
2. Another approach involved inserting directives like **#define DEVICE_1_ENABLED** within each **config.h** file. Subsequently, I designed a function within the source file, attempting to initialize configurations based on conditions such as:

```
void initConfig(){
    #ifdef DEVICE1
    #include "/device1_config/config.h"
    #endif
    // ... other devices
}
```

But... this solution didn't exactly make sense due to visibility issues. How would the **DEVICE1** be defined if the header-file wasn't established yet...

3. I explored the option of constructing a unified **config.h** file and employing **#ifdef** directives. However, I recognized that this approach would only configure at compile time, which didn't align with my requirements.

Additionally, my project entails the dynamic inclusion of various other files, such as **DEVICE1_regs.h** or **DEVICE2_regs.h**, among maybe five others. A resolution for the **config.h** issue could potentially extend to addressing these inclusion needs as well.

Comment: There are probably other questions asking about this.  It is also a question without a single good answer — it verges on being 'opinion-based'.  Nevertheless, it is a question that people need answered.  If you've not worked with software and had to think about the configuration, you need to find out from somewhere.  Often, in a corporate environment, there is precedent from other systems that the company has developed.

Comment: It's hard to state some universal rule for how to best do this. But in general,  `#ifdef` "compiler switches" in the C source are frowned upon and should be avoided, only to be used as a last resort. Not only is it hard to read, you risk maintenance bugs and "tight coupling" between unrelated things in the two products. Now if you have 2 different code bases, it might perhaps instead be reasonable to solve as much of this as possible with version control instead. Let them remain 2 projects but create a separate repo for all shared files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to select the configuration at runtime or do you rather mean at compile time? I'm asking because you went down the path with the preprocessor conditionals, which are processed at **compile time** and not at runtime.

I do not know the content of the configuration files, but if you really want to load them at runtime, maybe you are looking for an array of structs?
Where each struct would contain the device id and the content of the relevant config.h file, so that after reading the device id register you can select the correct struct from the array **at runtime**.

```
struct device_configuration
{
    uint8_t device_id;
    uint8_t cfg_value_0
    uint16_t cfg_value_1;
    uint32_t cfg_value_2;
};

// this is the content of all config.h files stored in the "configs" array
struct device_configuration configs[] = {
    {0xAB, 0x00, 0x0001, 0x00000002}, // device 1, device-id = 0xAB
    {0xBE, 0x00, 0x0001, 0x00000002}, // device 2, device-id = 0xBE
};

struct device_configuration* my_config = NULL;

// now you can select a configuration at runtime like this:
uint8_t device_id = read_devid_register();
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (configs[i].device_id == device_id) {
         my_config = &configs[i];
    }
}

// use config value to calibrate xtal or whatever
xtal_trim(my_config->cfg_value_0);
```

However, if you meant to select the relevant Header Files at compile time, because you want to build both devices from the same source but they have a different pinout or maybe device 1 is missing an external ic or something else, you could:

1. Encapsulate used modules/drivers with feature flags, which are enabled in the ide/makefile.
2. Based on the device you are compiling for, just set the correct include path to point to deviceN_config/.

For example, when compiling for device1 (i used gcc as an example here):

```
// compile for device 1
gcc -c -Idevice1_config/ source.c

// source.c
#include <config.h> // automatically selected device1_config/config.h because of the include path (-I option).
```